# A question about the convergence of series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If$\hspace{0.3cm}$ $\sum a_n$ and $\hspace{0.3cm}$$\sum b_n$$\hspace{0.3cm}$ are convergent  then which of the following is true?

$1.$$\hspace{0.3cm}$$a_{n+1}<a_n$$\hspace{0.3cm}$ $\forall n$

$2.$$\hspace{0.3cm}$$\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

$3.$$\hspace{0.3cm}$$a_n^2<a_n$$\hspace{0.3cm}$$ \forall n$

My Try:

$2$ is not true because i have a counter example

$a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

$1$ is also not true the same example

$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

I have problem about 3rd option.Please help me to prove or disprove it.Thanks

Comment: 1 is not true. eg. $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: Your counterexample of 3 is wrong. Square will always be positive (whereas your terms alternate)

Comment: One general hint for this kind of question that quickly rules out (1) and (3): whether a series converges depends on "long-term" behavior, but any finite collection of terms is irrelevant. So, very little will be true for all $n$. The first terms can be $100, 1000, 10000$, but the series can still converge if it "eventually" goes to zero sufficiently quickly.

Comment: yes  for 3 i put the wrong example

Comment: Efficient, one series takes care of 3 problems.

Comment: @AndréNicolas now i understand your comment.Thanks

Comment: Maybe, if you had added an assumption on the sign of $a_n$s and $b_n$s the problem would be more interesting!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding André Nicolas's answer, consider the same series you've used before, $$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}},$$ and consider $n=3$.